# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter

Intento obtener datos desde yahoo finances y me devuelve el siguiente error.

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance
name = 'GOOG'
ticker = yfinance.Ticker(name)
df = ticker.history(interval="1d",start="2000-01-4",end="2021-04-10")
x = df['Close']
df[:3]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-1698816b43b2> in <module>
      3 name = 'GOOG'
      4 ticker = yfinance.Ticker(name)
----> 5 df = ticker.history(interval="1d",start="2000-01-4",end="2021-04-10")
      6 x = df['Close']
      7 df[:3]

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/yfinance/base.py in history(self, period, interval, start, end, prepost, actions, auto_adjust, back_adjust, proxy, rounding, tz, **kwargs)
    153                                "Our engineers are working quickly to resolve "
    154                                "the issue. Thank you for your patience.")
--> 155         data = data.json()
    156 
    157         # Work with errors

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py in json(self, **kwargs)
    896                     # used.
    897                     pass
--> 898         return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
    899 
    900     @property

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py in loads(s, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    355             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    356             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 357         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    358     if cls is None:
    359         cls = JSONDecoder

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    335 
    336         """
--> 337         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    338         end = _w(s, end).end()
    339         if end != len(s):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

¿Cuál es la ausa? Agradeceré ayuda.

Comment: lo siento, no he podido replicar tu problema. Trata de tener lo módulos actualizados

Comment: ¿A ti te devuelve el DataFrame correctamente?

Comment: sip, puedes verlo [aqui](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1iTQxnoq2Uzl7X-01EW190AocIkq9I6HM?usp=sharing)

Comment: Tengo instalado yfinance. Lo hice en su día con conda. Ahora lo he actualizado y me sigue dando el mismo error. Me indicas que lo instale con pip.  Me puede dar lugar a algún problema?. En este entorno todo lo he instalado con conda.

Comment: Crea un entorno virtual con `python -m venv nombre` y has la instalación con pip. Puedes leer más del entorno virtual [aquí](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/venv.html)